# How to delete a message when the trash button is pressed, the trashed message should no longer be visible in the view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added a trash button which when pressed deletes the entire box/frame of message and this message gets stored in a toggle button(Trashed Messages:) which when clicked should toggle the view to display only the trashed messages. How to achieve that ?

HTML:

MESSAGE VIEWER

```
    <div><h2 id='starCounter' >Starred:</h2></div>
    <div><h2 id='trashCounter' >Trashed Messages:</h2></div>

    <figure class=frame id="box">
    <span class="helper"></span><img class= "profile1" src="widows2.jpg" alt="my img"/>
    <p>Twitter | Feb, 2017 <br><br>
    Message 1 from person Name. His Favourite music genre is pop</p>
    <button class="trash_btn" id="btn2" >Trash</button>
    <button class="btn-hold" id="btn1" data-text-swap=" Starred!">Star Message!</button>    
    <figcaption id="text">Name</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

CSS:

```
    .helper {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 95%;

        }
        .frame {
            height: 100px;      
            width: 100px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-align: center; 
            margin: 1em 0;
            padding: 20px;
            float: left;

        }

        .profile1 {
            background: #3A6F9A;
            float: left;
            vertical-align: left;
            max-height: 150px;
            max-width: 150px;
            justify-content: space-around;
             text-align: justify;
            width: [width of img];
        }

        #box {
            width: 1460px;
            justify-content: space-around;
            height: 150px; 
            box-sizing: 15px;
            border: 1px solid;

        }
```

JavaScript:

```
var count;
var star_count =0;
var button = document.querySelectorAll(".frame button")[1];
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if(this.classList.contains('btn-alt-color')){
    this.classList.remove('btn-alt-color');
    star_count--;
  } 
  else {
    this.classList.add('btn-alt-color');   
    star_count++;
  }
  console.log(star_count);
  document.getElementById("starCounter").innerText = "Starred: " +  star_count;

  if (button.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == button.innerHTML) {
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Please, include all relevant code as a [mcve]. JS is important to be shown here.

Comment: Please create a working example on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ofauz8yq/ : here is the working example

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the dom element on thrash button click. Wrap the html div in parent div and remove duplicate ids from buttons and figure.

Below is the running example

Html Code-

```
    <div>
    <h2 id='starCounter'>Starred:</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <h2 id='trashCounter'>Trashed Messages:</h2>
</div>
<div id="parent">
    <figure class=frame >
        <span class="helper"></span><img class="profile1" src="widows2.jpg" alt="my img" />
        <p>Twitter | Feb, 2017 <br><br>
            Message 1 from person Deep. His Favourite music genre is pop</p>
        <button class="trash_btn"  onclick="thrashMe(this)">Trash</button>
        <button class="btn-hold" id="btn1" data-text-swap=" Starred!">Star Message!</button>
        <figcaption id="text">Deep Mehta</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class=frame >
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img class="profile1" src="man-how-to.jpg" alt="my img" />
        <p>Twitter | Feb, 2017 <br><br>
            Message 1 from person Deep. His Favourite music genre is pop</p>
        <button class="trash_btn"  onclick="thrashMe(this)">Trash</button>
        <button class="btn-hold" data-text-swap="Starred!">Star Message!</button>
        <figcaption id="text">Tushar Kamble</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class=frame >
        <span class="helper"></span><img class="profile1" src="download.jpg" alt="my img" />
        <p>Twitter | Feb, 2017 <br><br>
            Message 1 from person Deep. His Favourite music genre is pop</p>
        <button class="trash_btn"  onclick="thrashMe(this)">Trash</button>
        <button class="btn-hold" data-text-swap="Starred!">Star Message!</button>
        <figcaption id="text">Parth Jaiswal</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class=frame >
        <span class="helper"></span><img class="profile1" src="images.jpg" alt="my img" />
        <p>Twitter | Feb, 2017 <br><br>
            Message 1 from person Deep. His Favourite music genre is pop</p>
        <button class="trash_btn"  onclick="thrashMe(this)">Trash</button>
        <button class="btn-hold" data-text-swap="Starred!">Star Message!</button>
        <figcaption id="text">Arnab Tarwani</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code-

```
<script>
    function thrashMe(obj) {
        document.getElementById("parent").removeChild(obj.closest("figure"));
    }
</script>
```